# appendTo() a specific div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I know I'm probably missing something simple but:

```js
var GAME_CANVAS_ELEMENT = $("<canvas id='Project-001-Canvas' class='Project-001-CSS'></canvas>");
GAME_CANVAS_ELEMENT.appendTo($('.a'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="a"></div>
```

This works if I `appendTo('body')` but if I attempt to append to anything else it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Your code is working fine - although you can improve it with just `.appendTo('.a')`. You can see the element is appended in the DOM inspector, although it's not visible as it has no content. If you still have issues with the code on your own site, check the console for errors and then edit the question to include them

Comment: Does it exist any element with "a" class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm wrapping your code inside `$(document).ready(function(){})` and with chrome it works: http://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/3701/

You can verify it by inspecting your html code with Chrome developer tool

Comment: So the issue must be related here somehow. Because wrapping my code like this, worked.